# How to automatically set the domain of a host interface in Foreman

Tags: foreman, provisioning, autodiscovery, bare-metal

I'm currently using [Foreman](https://theforeman.org/) to discover nodes on the network, and to provision bare metal servers.

When a node is discovered, and I "Provision" it through the Foreman UI, I always have to specify the "Domain" for the primary host interface that was discovered.

I have tried setting the Organization and Location for the given domain, but this doesn't work. I have also defined the Domain in the Network tab of the Host Group as well.

Is there a way to set the domain for the primary host interface  automatically so that I don't have to select it manually each time?

**EDIT: In the case where there is a single interface, the domain is set automatically via the Host Group, however when there are multiple interfaces, the domain does not get set**

Answer (score 0):

you can use a hostgroup to predefine it.

Comment: Can you elaborate?

Comment: I have already defined the Domain in the Network tab of the Host Group, and still no dice. I have also updated the question to include this.

Comment: Just found that setting the domain in the host group will get auto populated when there is only a single interface, but does not when there are multiple interfaces. Is there a way to set this when there are multiple interfaces?